# Add item SKU to this plugin

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I wanted a customized report for my website.
This extension gives most of the things i require from front end.
But i wanted to add product SKU in the report as well.

Below code is the controller which i think should be modified a little to add can someone help here.

```
<?php
class Cybernetikz_Salesreport_Adminhtml_SalesController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout()->renderLayout();
    }

    public function reportmanageAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout()->renderLayout();
    }

    public function exportCsvAction()
    {
        if ($data = $this->getRequest()->getPost()) {

            $orserstatus = "";
            $reportaddress = Mage::helper('salesreport')->getReportAddress();
            $addtess_title = ($reportaddress=="billing")?"Billing":"Shipping";
            $orders_csv_row ="Period,Order Id,Item Name,Qty,Unit Price,Row Total,$addtess_title Name,Email,Street Address,City,State,Postcode,Country";
            $orders_csv_row.="\n";

            $filter_type = $_REQUEST['filter_type'];

            $from = $_REQUEST['from'];
            $to = $_REQUEST['to'];

            $from_date = date('Y-m-d' . ' 00:00:00', strtotime($from));
            $to_date = date('Y-m-d' . ' 23:59:59', strtotime($to));

            $filter_model  = ($filter_type == 'shipping_date')
            ? 'sales/order_shipment_collection'
            : 'sales/order_collection';

            if($_REQUEST['show_order_statuses']>0){
                $orserstatus = $_REQUEST['order_statuses'];
                $_orderCollections = Mage::getResourceModel($filter_model);
                    $_orderCollections->addAttributeToSelect('*');
                    $_orderCollections->addFieldToFilter('created_at', array('from'=>$from_date, 'to'=>$to_date));
                    if($filter_type == 'order_date'){
                        $_orderCollections->addFieldToFilter('status', $orserstatus);
                    }  
                    $_orderCollections->setOrder('created_at', 'desc');              
                    $_orderCollections->load();
            }else{
                $_orderCollections = Mage::getResourceModel($filter_model)
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                    ->addFieldToFilter('created_at', array('from'=>$from_date, 'to'=>$to_date))
                    ->setOrder('created_at', 'desc')
                    ->load();
            }

            $i=0;
            foreach($_orderCollections as $key=>$single_order) {                
                if(($filter_type == 'shipping_date')){
                    $_orderId = $single_order->getOrderId();
                }else{
                    $_orderId = $single_order->getId();
                }

                $myOrder = Mage::getModel('sales/order');
                $myOrder->load($_orderId);

                //Some Random Fields
                if($reportaddress=="billing"){

                    $country_id = utf8_decode($myOrder->getBillingAddress()->getCountryId());
                    $country = Mage::getModel('directory/country')->load($country_id)->getName();

                    $name = utf8_decode($myOrder->getBillingAddress()->getFirstname()." ".$myOrder->getBillingAddress()->getLastname());

                    $billingaddress = $myOrder->getBillingAddress()->getStreet();
                    $address = "";
                    $address[] = utf8_decode($billingaddress[0]);
                    if($billingaddress[1]){
                        $address[] = utf8_decode($billingaddress[1]);
                    }
                    $address = implode(", ",$address);

                    $city = utf8_decode($myOrder->getBillingAddress()->getCity());

                    $region = utf8_decode($myOrder->getBillingAddress()->getRegion());

                    $postcode = utf8_decode($myOrder->getBillingAddress()->getPostcode());

                }else{

                    $country_id = utf8_decode($myOrder->getShippingAddress()->getCountryId());
                    $country = Mage::getModel('directory/country')->load($country_id)->getName();

                    $name = utf8_decode($myOrder->getShippingAddress()->getFirstname()." ".$myOrder->getShippingAddress()->getLastname());

                    $shippingaddress = $myOrder->getShippingAddress()->getStreet();
                    $address = "";
                    $address[] = utf8_decode($shippingaddress[0]);
                    if($shippingaddress[1]){
                        $address[] = utf8_decode($shippingaddress[1]);
                    }
                    $address = implode(", ",$address);

                    $city = utf8_decode($myOrder->getShippingAddress()->getCity());

                    $region = utf8_decode($myOrder->getShippingAddress()->getRegion());

                    $postcode = utf8_decode($myOrder->getShippingAddress()->getPostcode());
                }

                $myOrder->loadByIncrementId($myOrder->getIncrementId());

                $store = Mage::app()->getStore();
                $items = $myOrder->getItemsCollection();
                $ic=1;
                $countitems=0;

                $item_line="";
                foreach ($items as $itemId => $item){

                    if($item->getQtyToInvoice()!=0):
                        $itemorderqty = $item->getQtyToInvoice();
                    else:
                        $itemorderqty = round($item->getQtyOrdered());
                    endif;

                    if($item->getParentItemId() && round($item->getOriginalPrice())==0){
                        $parentitem = $myOrder->getItemById($item->getParentItemId());

                        $originalprice = $parentitem->getOriginalPrice();

                        $subtotal = ($parentitem->getOriginalPrice()*$itemorderqty);

                        $discountamount=0;              
                        if(round($parentitem->getDiscountAmount())!=0){
                            $discountamount=$parentitem->getDiscountAmount();
                            $subtotal=($subtotal-$discountamount);
                        }                       
                        $subtotal = number_format($subtotal,2);                     
                        $eachitemdiscountamount = ($discountamount/$itemorderqty);
                        $discountamount = number_format($eachitemdiscountamount,2);                     
                        $taxpercent = $parentitem->getTaxPercent();                     
                        $eachitemvat = $vatamount_eachproduct/$itemorderqty;                                                        
                        $totalvatdisamount = $eachitemvat+$eachitemdiscountamount;                          
                        $net_price = round($originalprice-($totalvatdisamount),2);                      
                    }else{                      
                        $originalprice = $item->getOriginalPrice();                     
                        $subtotal = ($item->getOriginalPrice()*$itemorderqty);                      
                        $discountamount=0;              
                        if(round($item->getDiscountAmount())!=0){
                            $discountamount=$item->getDiscountAmount();
                            $subtotal=($subtotal-$discountamount);
                        }                       
                        $subtotal = number_format($subtotal,2);                     
                        $eachitemdiscountamount = ($discountamount/$itemorderqty);
                        $discountamount = number_format($eachitemdiscountamount,2);                     
                        $taxpercent = $item->getTaxPercent();                       
                        $eachitemvat = $vatamount_eachproduct/$itemorderqty;                                                        
                        $totalvatdisamount = $eachitemvat+$eachitemdiscountamount;                          
                        $net_price = round($originalprice-($totalvatdisamount),2);
                    }

                    $customer_email = "";
                    if($custoer_id = $myOrder->getCustomerId()){
                        $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($custoer_id);
                        $customer_email = $customer->getEmail();
                    }

                    if(empty($customer_email)){
                        $customer_email=$myOrder->getCustomerEmail();
                    }                   

                    $datarow =  array(date("d/m/Y",strtotime($myOrder->getCreatedAt())), $myOrder->getIncrementId(), utf8_decode($item->getName()), $itemorderqty, utf8_decode($net_price),$subtotal,$name,$customer_email,$address,$city,$region,$postcode,$country);

                    $line = "";
                    $comma = "";
                    foreach($datarow as $titlename) {
                        $line .= $comma . str_replace(array(','),array(""), $titlename);
                        $comma = ",";
                    }

                    $line .= "\n";

                    $orders_csv_row .=$line;

                }
            }

            $reportname = Mage::helper('salesreport')->getReportName();
            $fileName   = $reportname.'.csv';
            $this->_sendUploadResponse($fileName, $orders_csv_row);
        }
    }

    protected function _sendUploadResponse($fileName, $content, $contentType='application/octet-stream')
    {
        $response = $this->getResponse();
        $response->setHeader('HTTP/1.1 200 OK','');
        $response->setHeader('Pragma', 'public', true);
        $response->setHeader('Cache-Control', 'must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0', true);
        $response->setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename='.$fileName);
        $response->setHeader('Last-Modified', date('r'));
        $response->setHeader('Accept-Ranges', 'bytes');
        $response->setHeader('Content-Length', strlen($content));
        $response->setHeader('Content-type', $contentType);
        $response->setBody($content);
        $response->sendResponse();
        die;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the following code, I have added one csv header **SKU** as header and **$item->getSku()** in code. Replace the following code.

```
<?php
class Cybernetikz_Salesreport_Adminhtml_SalesController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
public function indexAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout()->renderLayout();
}

public function reportmanageAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout()->renderLayout();
}

public function exportCsvAction()
{
    if ($data = $this->getRequest()->getPost()) {

        $orserstatus = "";
        $reportaddress = Mage::helper('salesreport')->getReportAddress();
        $addtess_title = ($reportaddress=="billing")?"Billing":"Shipping";
        $orders_csv_row ="Period,Order Id,Item Name,SKU,Qty,Unit Price,Row Total,$addtess_title Name,Email,Street Address,City,State,Postcode,Country";
        $orders_csv_row.="\n";

        $filter_type = $_REQUEST['filter_type'];

        $from = $_REQUEST['from'];
        $to = $_REQUEST['to'];

        $from_date = date('Y-m-d' . ' 00:00:00', strtotime($from));
        $to_date = date('Y-m-d' . ' 23:59:59', strtotime($to));

        $filter_model  = ($filter_type == 'shipping_date')
        ? 'sales/order_shipment_collection'
        : 'sales/order_collection';

        if($_REQUEST['show_order_statuses']>0){
            $orserstatus = $_REQUEST['order_statuses'];
            $_orderCollections = Mage::getResourceModel($filter_model);
                $_orderCollections->addAttributeToSelect('*');
                $_orderCollections->addFieldToFilter('created_at', array('from'=>$from_date, 'to'=>$to_date));
                if($filter_type == 'order_date'){
                    $_orderCollections->addFieldToFilter('status', $orserstatus);
                }  
                $_orderCollections->setOrder('created_at', 'desc');              
                $_orderCollections->load();
        }else{
            $_orderCollections = Mage::getResourceModel($filter_model)
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->addFieldToFilter('created_at', array('from'=>$from_date, 'to'=>$to_date))
                ->setOrder('created_at', 'desc')
                ->load();
        }

        $i=0;
        foreach($_orderCollections as $key=>$single_order) {                
            if(($filter_type == 'shipping_date')){
                $_orderId = $single_order->getOrderId();
            }else{
                $_orderId = $single_order->getId();
            }

            $myOrder = Mage::getModel('sales/order');
            $myOrder->load($_orderId);

            //Some Random Fields
            if($reportaddress=="billing"){

                $country_id = utf8_decode($myOrder->getBillingAddress()->getCountryId());
                $country = Mage::getModel('directory/country')->load($country_id)->getName();

                $name = utf8_decode($myOrder->getBillingAddress()->getFirstname()." ".$myOrder->getBillingAddress()->getLastname());

                $billingaddress = $myOrder->getBillingAddress()->getStreet();
                $address = "";
                $address[] = utf8_decode($billingaddress[0]);
                if($billingaddress[1]){
                    $address[] = utf8_decode($billingaddress[1]);
                }
                $address = implode(", ",$address);

                $city = utf8_decode($myOrder->getBillingAddress()->getCity());

                $region = utf8_decode($myOrder->getBillingAddress()->getRegion());

                $postcode = utf8_decode($myOrder->getBillingAddress()->getPostcode());

            }else{

                $country_id = utf8_decode($myOrder->getShippingAddress()->getCountryId());
                $country = Mage::getModel('directory/country')->load($country_id)->getName();

                $name = utf8_decode($myOrder->getShippingAddress()->getFirstname()." ".$myOrder->getShippingAddress()->getLastname());

                $shippingaddress = $myOrder->getShippingAddress()->getStreet();
                $address = "";
                $address[] = utf8_decode($shippingaddress[0]);
                if($shippingaddress[1]){
                    $address[] = utf8_decode($shippingaddress[1]);
                }
                $address = implode(", ",$address);

                $city = utf8_decode($myOrder->getShippingAddress()->getCity());

                $region = utf8_decode($myOrder->getShippingAddress()->getRegion());

                $postcode = utf8_decode($myOrder->getShippingAddress()->getPostcode());
            }

            $myOrder->loadByIncrementId($myOrder->getIncrementId());

            $store = Mage::app()->getStore();
            $items = $myOrder->getItemsCollection();
            $ic=1;
            $countitems=0;

            $item_line="";
            foreach ($items as $itemId => $item){

                if($item->getQtyToInvoice()!=0):
                    $itemorderqty = $item->getQtyToInvoice();
                else:
                    $itemorderqty = round($item->getQtyOrdered());
                endif;

                if($item->getParentItemId() && round($item->getOriginalPrice())==0){
                    $parentitem = $myOrder->getItemById($item->getParentItemId());

                    $originalprice = $parentitem->getOriginalPrice();

                    $subtotal = ($parentitem->getOriginalPrice()*$itemorderqty);

                    $discountamount=0;              
                    if(round($parentitem->getDiscountAmount())!=0){
                        $discountamount=$parentitem->getDiscountAmount();
                        $subtotal=($subtotal-$discountamount);
                    }                       
                    $subtotal = number_format($subtotal,2);                     
                    $eachitemdiscountamount = ($discountamount/$itemorderqty);
                    $discountamount = number_format($eachitemdiscountamount,2);                     
                    $taxpercent = $parentitem->getTaxPercent();                     
                    $eachitemvat = $vatamount_eachproduct/$itemorderqty;                                                        
                    $totalvatdisamount = $eachitemvat+$eachitemdiscountamount;                          
                    $net_price = round($originalprice-($totalvatdisamount),2);                      
                }else{                      
                    $originalprice = $item->getOriginalPrice();                     
                    $subtotal = ($item->getOriginalPrice()*$itemorderqty);                      
                    $discountamount=0;              
                    if(round($item->getDiscountAmount())!=0){
                        $discountamount=$item->getDiscountAmount();
                        $subtotal=($subtotal-$discountamount);
                    }                       
                    $subtotal = number_format($subtotal,2);                     
                    $eachitemdiscountamount = ($discountamount/$itemorderqty);
                    $discountamount = number_format($eachitemdiscountamount,2);                     
                    $taxpercent = $item->getTaxPercent();                       
                    $eachitemvat = $vatamount_eachproduct/$itemorderqty;                                                        
                    $totalvatdisamount = $eachitemvat+$eachitemdiscountamount;                          
                    $net_price = round($originalprice-($totalvatdisamount),2);
                }

                $customer_email = "";
                if($custoer_id = $myOrder->getCustomerId()){
                    $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($custoer_id);
                    $customer_email = $customer->getEmail();
                }

                if(empty($customer_email)){
                    $customer_email=$myOrder->getCustomerEmail();
                }                   

                $datarow =  array(date("d/m/Y",strtotime($myOrder->getCreatedAt())), $myOrder->getIncrementId(), utf8_decode($item->getName()),$item->getSku(), $itemorderqty, utf8_decode($net_price),$subtotal,$name,$customer_email,$address,$city,$region,$postcode,$country);

                $line = "";
                $comma = "";
                foreach($datarow as $titlename) {
                    $line .= $comma . str_replace(array(','),array(""), $titlename);
                    $comma = ",";
                }

                $line .= "\n";

                $orders_csv_row .=$line;

            }
        }

        $reportname = Mage::helper('salesreport')->getReportName();
        $fileName   = $reportname.'.csv';
        $this->_sendUploadResponse($fileName, $orders_csv_row);
    }
}

protected function _sendUploadResponse($fileName, $content, $contentType='application/octet-stream')
{
    $response = $this->getResponse();
    $response->setHeader('HTTP/1.1 200 OK','');
    $response->setHeader('Pragma', 'public', true);
    $response->setHeader('Cache-Control', 'must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0', true);
    $response->setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename='.$fileName);
    $response->setHeader('Last-Modified', date('r'));
    $response->setHeader('Accept-Ranges', 'bytes');
    $response->setHeader('Content-Length', strlen($content));
    $response->setHeader('Content-type', $contentType);
    $response->setBody($content);
    $response->sendResponse();
    die;
}
```

}

Hope this helps.!!!

Comment: Welcome.. :) Post more.

Comment: Actually i wanted to request one more thing, if it is easy. The drop down has Order Created Date, Can a Drop down also have Order Updated Date and give report accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

Around line no. 124

```
foreach ($items as $itemId => $item){
$itemSku = $item->getSku();
...
}
```

Comment: The above answer worked for me .. Thank you.. :)